# How can I index files and those files content into ElasticSearch using ApacheLucene?

Tags: java, apache, elasticsearch, lucene

I'm pretty new in data analyzing and right now I'm trying to index some files and their content into elastic search using apache lucene tokenizer.
Here is my method in which I'm using apache tokenizer

```
 public List<String> getFilesContentWithLucene() throws IOException {
        folderList = getFilesFromFolders(folderName);
        Analyzer tokenizer = null;
        for (File file : folderList) {
            if (file.getName().endsWith(".txt")) {
                StringReader reader = new StringReader(parseFile(file).toString());
                TokenStream stream  = tokenizer.tokenStream(null, reader);
                stream.reset();
                try {
                    while(stream.incrementToken()) {
                        documentTerms.add(stream.getAttribute(CharTermAttribute.class).toString());
                    }
                    stream.end();
                    stream.close();
                }
                catch(IOException e) {
                    // not thrown b/c we're using a string reader...
                }
                documentTermsMap.put(file.getName().replace(".txt",""), documentTerms);
            }
        }

        return documentTerms;
    }
```

My questions are:
What means the field parameter for apache tokenizer ? 
TokenStream stream  = tokenizer.tokenStream(null, reader) in this form it throws me NullPointer exception;
How can I use index files and their content into elastic search ?

Comment: the null pointer exception issue I solved by initializing the analyzer with new StandardAnalyzer.